# Transform Epoch UTC to String EST using momentjs

Tags: timezone, momentjs, timezone-offset

I have two input variables: an epoch time in UTC time zone and the name of the actual time zone. How do I get a formatted day/time using moment.js that would take in account the DST changes. I tried this code but it doesn't do the trick. What am I doing wrong, please?

```
var abs_time = 1611188219.277; // this is UTC coresponding to 1/21/2021 18:31:37 UTC
var timezone = "America/New_York"; // this the actual time zone

var mom = moment(abs_time * 1000).format();
var date_time = moment.tz(mom, timezone).format('ddd, MMM DD YYYY - HH:mm');
console.log(date_time);

//actual result: Thu, Jan 21 2021 - 18:31
//desired result: Thu, Jan 21 2021 - 13:31 - in the summer this should only be 4 hour difference
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `1611188219.277` actually corresponds to `2021-01-21T00:16:59.277Z`, not the time you gave in your question (assuming it is a Unix timestamp with seconds precision).  This can be seen with the following code:

```js
const d = new Date(1611188219.277 * 1000);
const s = d.toISOString();
console.log(s);
```

You can get the equivalent local time in a specific time zone without any libraries, as long as you're satisfied with the output produced by the [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) function.

```js
const d = new Date(1611188219.277 * 1000);
const s = d.toLocaleString(undefined, { timeZone: 'America/New_York' });
console.log(s);
```

Note that `undefined` in the above code will use the browser's current language.  If you want a specific language, you could pass its language code there instead (such as `en` or `en-US`, etc.)

In general, due to [its project status](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/), you should avoid using Moment unless it's already being used in an existing project.  If however, you must use Moment and Moment-TimeZone for this, you can do the following to get the same result:

```js
const m = moment.tz(1611188219.277 * 1000, 'America/New_York');
const s = m.format('ddd, MMM DD YYYY - HH:mm');
console.log(s);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.32/moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.min.js"></script>
```

I used the same format from your question, but of course you could change this as desired.

You might also consider using [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) (the successor to Moment), or [Date-fns](https://date-fns.org/), or several other libraries.

And yes, all of the above will correctly take daylight saving time into account.

Comment: Excellent. Precisely what I needed. Thank you.